# Using boolean to print invalid commands in Java

Tags: java, boolean

I am trying to build my own command line interface.

The most confusing part is to print out the invalid command base on user input.

I tried using a boolean function to check each commands for its validity.

I want my program to continue even if my command is invalid.

How do I get into a `while` loop again after I got out of it?

```
String command;
BufferedReader console = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
boolean R = true;

while (R==true) {
    System.out.print("Command: ");
    command = console.readLine();

    R = false;

    ArrayList commandParams = new ArrayList();
    String[] commandSplit = command.split(" ");

    if (commandSplit.length > 1) {
        for (int i = 1; i < commandSplit.length; i++) {
            commandParams.add(commandSplit[i]);
        }
    }

    if (commandSplit[0].equals("time")) {
        Date time = new Date();

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss ");
        System.out.println(sdf.format(time));
        R = true;
    }

    // Print today's date.
    if (commandSplit[0].equals("date")) {
        Date date = new Date();

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(" YYYY/MM/DD");
        System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
        R = true;
    }

    // Exit the console when "exit" is entered.
    if (commandSplit[0].equals("exit")) {
        System.exit(0);
        R = true;
    }
}
System.out.println("Invalid command");

System.out.print("Command: ");
command = console.readLine();
```

Comment: you are almost there, all you have to do is to remove  R=false; and set this value as false only when the user decides to end the session.  One question for you is why do you have command = console.readLine(); at the end of the program, I missed getting this.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/368151/17034

Answer (score 0):

Move the code for the invalid command inside the loop i.e

```
while (R==true) {


        System.out.print("command: ");


        command = console.readLine();
        R=false;

       ...

        //Exit the console when "exit" is entered.
        if (commandSplit[0].equals("exit")) {
            System.exit(0);
            R=true;
        }

        if(R==false){
            System.out.println("invalid command");
            R=true;
        }       
    }              
}
```

Comment: The user enters exit when he intends to come out of the console. But since the boolean flag (R) is set the program never terminates right?

Comment: @User27854 he calls `System.exit(0)` if the command equals "exit" so the program will terminate.

Comment: I missed that, sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. You don't even need a boolean variable.

```
while (true) {
    String command = console.readLine();
    if (command.equals("date")) {
        //print date
        continue;
    }
    if (command.equals("time")) {
        //print time
        continue;
    }
    if (command.equals("exit")) {
        break;
    }
    System.out.println("invalid command");        
    command = console.readLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The concrete answer: You can't get back into it.

But think about it: Do you really need to set your boolean variable to false every time? No, it's only needed when you want to terminate the program.

You could use a lot of if-else statements but since JDK 7 we are finally able to compare strings in a switch-case structure which would fit your needs perfectly:

```
boolean loop = true;
while ( loop )
{
  // Your read and parse functions go here...
  switch ( commandSplit[ 0 ] )
  {
    case "exit":
      loop = false;
      break;
    case "time":
      // dummy method
      printTime();
      break;
    // default will be executed if none of the above cases is met.
    default:
      System.out.println( "Invalid / Unknown command." );
      break;

  }
}
// shutdown logic goes here (if needed).
```

Doing so would allow you easily to extend the functionallity of your program since you easily add a new case if you want to implement a new command.